# Unexpected Puppet notify order

Tags: puppet

I'm using the puppet vm to follow the puppet tutorial, and have the following manifest:

```
# /root/learning-manifests/2.file.pp

file {
  '/tmp/test1':
  ensure        => present,
  content => "Hi.",
}

file {
  '/tmp/test2':
  ensure     => directory,
  mode => 0644,
}

file {
  '/tmp/test3':
  ensure       => link,
  target => '/tmp/test1',
}

notify {
  "I'm notifying you.":
}

notify {
  "So am I!":
}
```

My expected output is:

```
notice: I'm notifying you.
notice: /Stage[main]//Notify[I'm notifying you.]/message: defined 'message' as 'I'm notifying you.'
notice: So am I!
notice: /Stage[main]//Notify[So am I!]/message: defined 'message' as 'So am I!'
```

My actual output is:

```
notice: So am I!
notice: /Stage[main]//Notify[So am I!]/message: defined 'message' as 'So am I!'
notice: I'm notifying you.
notice: /Stage[main]//Notify[I'm notifying you.]/message: defined 'message' as 'I'm notifying you.'
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.06 seconds
```

Can someone please explain why my notices are transposed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in [this PuppetLabs wiki page about Puppet ordering:](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html)

> Puppet might sync them in any order: unlike with a procedural language, the physical order of resources in a manifest doesn’t imply a logical order.

You should use before, require, notify, subscribe to define dependencies between resources in your manifests. Also, you can define your dependencies by chaining your resource references. E.g:

```
notify {
  "I'm notifying you.":
}
-> 
notify {
  "So am I!":
}
```

Comment: Ordering came later in the tutorial - thanks for the example

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee order of execution in puppet you need to have some class hierarchy.

Definitions inside single class can be executed in any order, you cannot influence that.