# Order of resource/class execution in puppet manifest file

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I working on configuring CQ5 on vagrant managed virtual machine. The provisioning is done using puppet. I have query regards to the order of execution of classes/resources in puppet manifest file.

Please find below manifest file cqsite.pp

```
include java
include apache
cq::instance {myauthor:
      installation_type => author,
    }

cq::instance {mypublish:
      installation_type => publish,
    }
```

During provision puppet is initially picking cq resources (cq::instance ) rather than java. But java must be installed first to execute few commands in cq::instance.pp file. So its throwing an error. Please help me in finding solution for this

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected Puppet notify order](http://serverfault.com/questions/460206/unexpected-puppet-notify-order)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not specifying any resource dependencies so Puppet will apply the changes in a seemingly random order.

If the `java` class should be installed before your `cq::instance` definitions, then you should add an explicit dependency like so:

```
cq::instance { myauthor:
  installation_type => author,
  require           => Class['java']
}
```

Or even:

```
Class['java'] -> Cq::Instance <| |>
```

See https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html

Comment: `Puppet will apply the changes in a seemingly random order.` - Of course if you have new enough version of puppet you can use `ordering = manifest`.  Explicitly stating relationships, like you suggested, is strongly prefered to make your manifests more readable.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of manifest ordering and that these days the order isn't truly random however I'm reluctant to state manifest ordering as a solution as I feel it reinforces a misunderstanding of Puppet as a scripting language. Also, a module should not have to dictate this global setting because the module author doesn't explicitly state relationships between resources.